# Cómo copiar unos registros en SQLite

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, sqlite, qt

Tengo una base de datos con varias tablas. Una de ellas tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE `SetupUni` (
    `Uni_ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `SetupName` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `AssessmentGroup`   TEXT,
    `Assessment`    TEXT,
    `Quantity`  TEXT,
    `Selection` INTEGER NOT NULL,
);
```

tengo varios registros creados donde el `SetupName`es `SetupInicial`. Ahora quiero insertar en la tabla una copia de estos registros pero dandoles otro nombre, por ejemplo `SetupCopia`.

Tal que quede algo así:

```
Uni_ID   SetupName           AssessmentGroup   Assessment   Quantity   Selection
"493"   "SetupInicial"       "Running Safety"   "ΣY_max "   "Y1_1"      "0"
"494"   "SetupInicial"       "Running Safety"   "ΣY_max "   "Y2_1"      "0"
"495"   "SetupInicial"       "Running Safety"   "ΣY_max "   "Y4_1"      "0"
"496"   "SetupCopia"         "Running Safety"   "ΣY_max "   "Y1_1"      "0"
"497"   "SetupCopia"         "Running Safety"   "ΣY_max "   "Y2_1"      "0"
"498"   "SetupCopia"         "Running Safety"   "ΣY_max "   "Y4_1"      "0"
```

He probado a usar esta sentencia:

```
    INSERT INTO 
SetupUni (SetupName, AssessmentGroup, Assessment, Quantity, Selection)
SELECT SetupName,AssessmentGroup,Assessment,Quantity, Selection 
FROM SetupUni 
WHERE SetupName=SetupInicial
```

Lo que me copia los registros pero manteniendo el nombre original. ¿Cómo haría para poder cambiar luego el nombre solo a los que he copiado? O ¿Cómo haría para copiar pero en el campo `SetupName` dandole yo el nombre?
¿Es posible esto que planteo?

También comentar que finalmente quiero introducir la sentencia a través de Qt, donde no admite hacer `bindValue()`en los SELECT, pero sí en el WHERE e INSERT INTO y UPDATE.

Aquí un ejemplo de sentencia SQL en Qt:

```
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("UPDATE SetupList SET SetupName=? WHERE Setup_ID=?");
    query.addBindValue(value);
    query.addBindValue(theID);
    query.exec();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Qt puedes hacerlo perfectamente sin ningún problema. Aprovechando la sentencia SQL que te indica @Guillem puedes crear la sentencia con QString:

```
QString nuevoNombre("testNombre");
QString queryStr;
queryStr = QString("INSERT INTO SetupUni (SetupName, AssessmentGroup, Assessment, Quantity, Selection) SELECT '%1',AssessmentGroup,Assessment,Quantity, Selection FROM SetupUni WHERE SetupName=SetupInicial").arg(nuevoNombre);

if(query.exec(queryStr))
{
    qDebug() << "Todo ha ido bien";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error:" << query.lastError().text();
}
```

Es lo que yo suelo hacer. Creo la sentencia SQL con QString, con toda la libertad que eso me da y luego la ejecuto.

Espero haberte ayudado y que te sirva.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Una respuesta muy útil :) Me ha servido 100%

Answer (score 1):

Si es el mismo nombre para todos, podrias hacerlo así:

```
INSERT INTO 
SetupUni (SetupName, AssessmentGroup, Assessment, Quantity, Selection)
SELECT 'SetupCopia',AssessmentGroup,Assessment,Quantity, Selection 
FROM SetupUni 
WHERE SetupName=SetupInicial
```

Comment: La respuesta me funciona bien en SQLite, pero en Qt no puedo crear ese tipo de sentencias así. Habría alguna otra forma de hacerlo? Por si no conoces Qt, ahí no se pueden añadir tus propios valores dentro de un SELECT.

Comment: Disculpa, no conozco Qt, pero entonces entiendo que no es un problema de SQL ni SQLlite, si no de Qt, no? Por lo que también entiendo que la query la lanzas así? `QSqlQuery query("SELECT country FROM artist");` y no puedes hacer `QSqlQuery query("SELECT \'country\' FROM artist");` o similares?

Comment: No sabía que en SQL se podia hacer así, así que pensaba que el resultado de SQL podría aplicarlo a Qt sin problema. Pero me equivocaba, la solución que tu das si que me crea el problema de Qt. Gracias por la ayuda igualmente, pues no sabía que en SQLite se podía hacer eso.

Comment: @MAP entonces solucionaste tu problema?

Comment: Ahora se como hacerlo en SQL pero sigo sin saber hacerlo en Qt.